# Replace value in a column using apply

Tags: r, apply

I'm trying to update two columns of a huge dataset( > 45 mill rows).
Basically the columns are a character format and I'm trying to convert it to a number.
This is the sample data 's1':

```
id path convert               start                stop
1  1    0        05SEP2015:12:38:55  05SEP2015:12:38:55
2  1    0        09SEP2015:01:22:54  09SEP2015:01:22:54
```

I'm using the following code:

```
library(lubridate)

apply(s1, 1, function(row){

  s1$Start <- as.numeric(dmy_hms(row[4]))

  #Similarly code for stop column
  # s1$stop <- as.numeric(dmy_hms(row[5]

  return(s1)

})
```

Basically i want to convert the start text to a date and then change it to a number and then replace it in the data frame itself.

So i'm expecting an output like this :

```
[[1]]
id path convert       start                stop
1  1    0        1441456735  05SEP2015:12:38:55
2  1    0        1441761774  09SEP2015:01:22:54
```

but I'm getting :

```
[[1]]
id path convert       start                stop
1  1    0        1441456735  05SEP2015:12:38:55
2  1    0        1441456735  09SEP2015:01:22:54
[[2]]
id path convert       start                stop
1  1    0        1441761774  05SEP2015:12:38:55
2  1    0        1441761774  09SEP2015:01:22:54
```

It looks like its making a list of data frames which I don't want.

Any pointers regarding this, as I'm so near yet so far.

Comment: why not just `s1[,"start"] = as.numeric(dmy_hms(s1[,"start"]))` ?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just

```
s1[,"start"] = as.numeric(dmy_hms(s1[,"start"]))
```

and

```
s1[,"stop"] = as.numeric(dmy_hms(s1[,"stop"]))
```

Comment: as.numeric(dmy_hms(s1[,"start"])) return me a NA as s1[,"Start"] return me "Start"...(not sure exactly why)
But i realized I was just overcomplicating things by trying to sue lapply.

This works for the subset s1 :
s1$Start <- as.numeric(dmy_hms(s1$Start)) 

Will try to run it on my entire dataset..need to find out how much time does that take.

Thanks for pointing out the obvious !! 
Cheers!

Comment: you mean `s1[1,"Start"]` is the word "Start"? In which case you may not be reading your data correctly if the first line is header, use `header=TRUE` when reading it. If there are `NAs` produced, it may be because of missing data (in which case `na.omit` can remove them if that's what you wan)

Comment: I'm using fread to reada my data in and by default it takes in the headers. (There is no missing data)

Comment: not sure what you mean by 'takes in the headers' , you need to make sure that first row of data `s1[1,]` contains the data, not the column names